# Even Distribution

Tags: objective-c, c, game-engine

Say I have turn based game with 20 attack turns and the players attack speed determines how often they get to attack, how would you calculate and or graph a table of "who attacks when" when one person has an attack speed of 5 and another a speed of 8? (These are test values, the values I will be using will vary. 20 attack turns will be the cap, however, each player will be able to invest in their own attack speed with their skill points up to a value of 10)

I've been programming in C for about a 2 years and I'm currently playing with Obj-C making my first indy game, any advise or knowledge would be of great help.

Comment: What exactly does attack speed do?

Comment: @Jeremy Since I play(ed) Pokemon, basically whoever's attack speed is higher, they will have the best chance of going first. Also it enables them to attack more than once (if their attack speed is high enough). (I'm just guessing this is the case in his app, correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm basing it off of. The higher the attack speed the more often they get their chance to go, so if you have an attack speed of 5 and I have an attack speed of 10 I get two moves for every one of yours, however you could have spend all your skill points in damage doing twice as much as me. So it more or less cancels out

Comment: Questions about game design should go to gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (playerTwoWent == 0)
    {
        difference = difference - player_twos_speed;
    }
    else if (playerTwoWent == 1)
    {
        difference      = player_ones_speed + difference;
        playerTwoWent   = 0;
    }

    if (difference >= 0)
    {
        printf("player 1s turn: %d\n", difference);
    }
    else if (difference < 0)
    {
        if (playerTwoWent == 0)
        {
            printf("player 2s turn: %d\n", difference);

            playerTwoWent = 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly:

The first to attack will be `min(a,b)`, where `a` and `b` are your initial "attack speeds", 5 and 8. Then subtract the min value of both, and if the result is 0 or less add the attacker's original value again. So after the first attack, `a=5` again, but now `b=8-5=3`. Then it's b's turn:

```
a = 5 - 8 = -3
b = 3 - 8 = -5
```

Both less than zero, so add 5 and 8 again:

```
a = 2
b = 3
```

a attacks:

```
a = -3 -> a = 2
b = -2 -> b = 6
```

and thus a gets to score another hit. And so on, until you get a tie -- you're bound to run into that one way or another. You could return a "tie" result, or let the last attacker or last defender "win" that one. Put some thought in this, because what if both players have the same "attack" value?

Comment: Fantastic way to look at it. As far as the stats go I am having a few friends over tonight to play through the combat system with pen and paper to see if the systems balanced. I'm putting a lot of thought into this and I thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Your solution was so simple I feel like a goof. It works great after I tested it for a bit, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

This math problem tells me who’s turn is when -

For example:
There’s 11 attacks
you attack 8 times and your enemy attacks 3
Determine an attack sequence thats evenly distributed and consistently repeatable.

In this case:
1. player 1 attacks
2. player 1 attacks
3. player 2 attacks
4. player 1 attacks
5. player 1 attacks
6. player 1 attacks
7. player 2 attacks
8. player 1 attacks
9. player 1 attacks
10. player 1 attacks
11. player 2 attacks
(repeat these 11 steps as long as needed)

I first thought the solution would be best done with division until I ran into 20 walls, so

I choose subtraction bc it can be reproduced and works better programmatically, instead of creating an attack sequence by division and storing it as an array and indexing the array each time you need to determine a persons turn.

so my code to do this was: